# How to write an regular expression including brackets in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get data from JavaScript code which is:

```
var _pd =_RP("blablabla");
```

When I use:

```
RegExp('var _pd =_RP(.*?);').exec('var _pd =_RP("blablabla");');
```

I can get `("blablabla")`. But what I want to get is just `blablabla`.

So I tried:

```
'var _pd =_RP\("(.*?)"\);'
```

But I can't get what I want and it just returns null value.

How can I get the raw data (in this case just `blablabla`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the regex string:

```js
let result = RegExp('var _pd =_RP\\("(.*?)"\\);').exec('var _pd =_RP("blablabla");');

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you can use a regex literal:

```js
let result = /var _pd =_RP\("(.*?)"\);/.exec('var _pd =_RP("blablabla");');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks it works. By the way I thought escaping the backslashes only needs a single'\' but why does it has to be '\\'?

Comment: The first backslash is eaten by the javascript string as the escape  for the next character. So `\(`  becomes an 'escaped' ( which is just (.


console.log('\(') => (

`\\` gives an escaped \ which is a \

console.log('\\(') => \(

Easier to us a regex literal :)